# Python read oldest file first

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have object and attributes data in separate csv files. there are 3 different types of objects.

Directory may contain different files but I have to read and process object and attribute files. After reading the object file and then will have to read respective attribute file.

Below is code and files

```
plant = []
flower = []
person = []

for file_name in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)):
        if file_name.startswith('plant_file'):
            plant.append(file_name)
        if file_name.startswith('person_file'):
            person.append(file_name)
        if file_name.startswith('flower_file'):
            flower.append(file_name) 

for file_name in person:
    object_file_path = dir_path + file_name
    attribute_file_path = dir_path + file_name.replace('file','attributes_file')
    read_object_csv = pd.read_csv(object_file_path)
    read_attribute_csv = pd.read_csv(attribute_file_path)
   

for file_name in flower:
    object_file_path = dir_path + file_name
    attribute_file_path = dir_path + file_name.replace('file','attributes_file')
    read_object_csv = pd.read_csv(object_file_path)
    read_attribute_csv = pd.read_csv(attribute_file_path)
```

file name contains date and time in the format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` . Sample file names are

```
plant_attributes_file_20221013134403.csv
plant_attributes_file_20221013142151.csv
plant_attributes_file_20221013142455.csv

plant_file_20221013134403.csv
plant_file_20221013142151.csv
plant_file_20221013142455.csv

person_file_20221012134948.csv
person_file_20221012140706.csv
person_attributes_file_20221012134948.csv
person_attributes_file_20221012140706.csv
```

How can we sort file names in list using timestamp, so that oldest file can be loaded first and load latest file at last ?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski the reverse is unnecessary, he wants the oldest first, ie: the smallest.

Comment: Because of the format of your date, you should be able sort without parsing out the date: `plant.sort()`